# if there is a way to access to the component's node in the component?

Tags: svelte

I have a code:

```
<Rg_select select={countriesList} />
<Rg_select select={citiesList} />
<Rg_select select={familiesList} />
```

Inside each component I need an access to its DOM (namely, root element). Is any way to get this?

adding `bind:this={Rg_select}` will not work obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Svelte components do not always have a single root element so the exact thing that you're asking for is not possible.

However, there are multiple workarounds. For example, you could access the DOM element in the component itself by using:

```html
<!-- inside component -->
< .... bind:this={componentDOMElement} .. />
```

And then export that variable like this:

```js
export let componentDOMElement
```

Which will enable you to bind to it in the parent.

Comment: I meant I need access to component's DOM inside component itself, for parent get to know what is provider of an event.
e.g.
`if(countryList.changed){...}
 if(cityList.changed){...}`

Comment: Solved in easier way: added `ref` props to components,  and then  `export let ref` in each comp.